# How to completely empty wallets - problem with fees

Tags: transaction-fees, litecoin

I have some Bitcoin and Litecoin wallets with very small amount of BTC/LTC in them.

I want to completely empty these wallets - send all the BTC/LTC them to another address. This address can belong to me or to the others (donation etc.).

The Bitcoin-Qt doesn't allow to send from these wallets because transaction fees are higher than the amount in the wallets. It seems that I cannot "force" this client to use smaller fees or even no fee at all.

Can I use other wallets to do this? Which ones (Electrum?)?

What alternatives do I have with with Litecoins? There seems to be only one reasonable client (Litecoin-Qt).

Comment: What do you mean by transaction fees are higher than amounts in the wallets? You should be able to set it as very low, or set the config to set the transaction fee as 0.0001 or lower. What platform are you using? https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

Two options, depending on your skill level and comfortability with command-line:

1. Try updating your settings in `bitcoin.conf` to allow a low (or none) transaction fee:
   https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File
2. Try running in `./bitcoind` in command-line with the option `-paytxfee=<amt>` with whatever amount you can pay to transfer these balances out. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Linux_Quickstart